# Is possible to associate a text to a JTableHeader without a table?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

I want to create a JTable with a header inside some cells. But I want to associate a text with this header. Is it possible? How to do?

All my best!
Leandro Lima

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only way to do it I found was to create a table, without cells and with a column with a header title. So I get this header and put it inside other table by cell renderer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question then you can create a panel using a BorderLayout. You add the table to the CENTER and the table header to the NORTH.

Comment: Something like that. But the idea is to create a row header I'll put a header in each cell from the first column. I can do it ok, but I don't know how to set the header text.

Answer (score 0):

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(x).setHeaderValue( "text" );
```

Comment: Hi Nate, thanks for this solution, but I don't have a table with columns, just the JTableHeader.